# How to get XOR-routing of two components with React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

My App - compoment looks something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Route path='/:category?/:post?' component={Posts}/>
                <Route exact path='/edit' component={PostForm}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that I want to have XOR-behavior, i.e. when the first component is rendered, I don't want the second one to be rendered and vice versa. What I actually got is that with an URL like localhost3000/books/123344 only the first component is rendered, but with the URL localhost3000/create , both components are rendered .

What is the reason for this and how can I get the desired XOR-rendering of the two components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use react-router [switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch), it will only render one component. Also switch the order of the routes.

Try this:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/edit' component={PostForm}/>
    <Route path='/:category?/:post?' component={Posts}/>
</Switch>
```

Comment: You brought up two interesting new concepts. Does the order matter in <Router/>  tags, as well?

Comment: not in case where all the routes path have different value, but in your case you are using route params (not fixed value), so if you define the `/:category` route first then it will match with all the path and same component will render always.